# How to clip an image inside div?

Tags: css

I have an `img` inside `div`. I want the image to be clipped off (half or three-fourth) using CSS.

*E.g.*: In the example from below: the final image should get cut, as specified by the user, either by 50%, 75%, etc.

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-2">
    <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/rgjfL2bw/)

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rgjfL2bw/1/)?

Comment: Can jQuery be used ?

Comment: @Pugazh, no it cannot.

Comment: Do you have a fixed width and height for the image?

Comment: @Huelfe, yeah not vertically, but horizontally.

Comment: @Zentryn, the width is getting restricted from `col-xs-6`.

Comment: If you know the amount of pixels, you can use this http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_clip